# Как изменить стили php-страницы, не изменяя сss-код на других?

Tags: php, css, вёрстка

Добрый день. Есть следующая ситуация: имеется одна шаблонная php-страница, в которую посредством команды `include` импортируется head, хедер, левое меню и футер. На странице "Контакты" появилась необходимость изменить стили, как это сделать, не меняя стиль общего шаблона main.css? Спасибо, надеюсь, задал понятно, было трудно сформулировать :) P.S. решал вопрос, посредством добавления в html-код `<style>`, но мне сказали, что это неправильно.

Comment: А что мешает создать отдельный contacts.css? И подключить его через `@import url('styles/conacts.css')` внутри `main.css`. Ну или подключить его через `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="urlCSSFiles">`

Comment: @sergei1094 т.е head не импортировать, а прописать в contacts.php?

Comment: Если у вас разная структура html-разметки между одной и другой страницей, то желаемо всё-же создать отдельный файл со стилями и поместить его рядом с main.css. А уже в вашем инклюде header.php дописать `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/contacts.css">`

Comment: @sergei1094 пожалуйста, можно поточнее, куда именно дописывать путь к contacts.css? В сам код header или в код вставки <?php include "file_path"?> ? Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предполагается что по пути `file_path` у вас допустим находится скрипт **header.php** примерно некого содержания:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Hello World!!</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/main.css' />
    <!-- Вот именно сюда и подключаете ваш новый CSS -->
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/contacts.css' />
    <!-- Между тегами <head> и </head> -->
</head>
......
```

Либо можно открыть ваш main.css и в нём добавить в самом верху импорт другого файла стилей:

```
//main.css
@import url("conacts.css");

.exampleClass {
  ...
}
#exampleId{
  ...
}
```

Я думаю что понятно более чем достаточно) В некоторых ситуациях всё-равно разработчикам приходится использовать стили для объектов через теги внутри кода.

Например: `<div class="content" style="margin: 5px;"></div>` и в этом ничего страшного нет.

Comment: А если действовать первым методом, то куда девать старое подключение main.css?

Comment: При этом, используя второй способ, не должны повторяться классы, id и пр., иначе отредактируется всё на главной странице?

Comment: )) Никуда не надо его девать. Просто продублируйте `<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/main.css' /><link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/contacts.css' />`

Comment: Спасибо, а как указать браузеру, что нужно выбрать, например, второй css, а не main на моей странице "Контакты"?

Comment: А чем будет мешать main?

Comment: @просто там совершенно другие параметры, которые на странице "Контакты", хотелось бы изменить. Например, with у #content-wrapper сделать чуть меньше, со 100% на 80% и ещё много чего)

Comment: Вы можете изменять уже установленные параметры так как вам угодно. Вам бы лучше не много изучить информацию о доступах к уже существующим классам и понять структуру DOOM. Море полезной информации а так же `Одновременное использование разных классов` вы найдёте на http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/klassy